# Why is sample variance notated as $\frac{S_{x x}}{n-1}$?

Tags: variance, notation

I'm going through my class textbook and it defines sample variance as this: $$s^2 = \frac{\sum (x_i - \bar x)^2}{n-1} = \frac{S_{x x}}{n-1}$$
What exactly does $S_{x x}$ mean? Is it always synonymous with $\sum(x_i - \bar x)^2$?

Comment: No, it simply is a notation from your textbook. You should not put too much belief on the consistency of notations across the literature.

Comment: +1 what @Xi'an said. Definitions must be provided in the textbook so don't worry about that. For example in Hayashi's Econometrics (Hayashi, 2000. Chapter 2.3, Equation 2.3.6), $S_{XX}=\frac{X'X}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i'$, where $X$ is the regressor matrix and $x_i$ is a column-vector representing the ith row of $X$.

Comment: $S_{ab}$ will usually mean a sum of squares of products of terms involving values labelled a and b (in this case the terms both involve x since both subscripts were x), but its *exact* definition will depend on context. Always look to see how its defined (which in this case is contained in the parts you quote in your question). Absent context I would tend to assume the simplest of the common cases, which would be the sum of squares-of-products-of-deviations-from-means definition you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly we can't take notation definitions for granted, but I think the $S$ means the summation, the first subscript $X$ means $(x_i - \bar{x})$ and the second subscript means the same and together it becomes squared and thus the final form.

This kind of notation is not unusual. For example, if you study the formula above the [Properties section of the wiki for covariance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties).

Answer (score 4):

The notation convention reflects a general formula for $S_{xy}=\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)$, which is used to obtain covariance. Hence, you can write $S_{xx}$ to calculate the sum for the variance. It just looks neat to math folks who prefer not to overcrowd already densely populated notation zoo. They try to stick to mnemonics when they can, so S in this case stands for "sum" while  its indices indicate which variables - de-meaned ones too! - are being summed.

Also, remember that other people in other places may use them $S_{xy}$ to mean something entirely different.